# Deploying changes to Docker and its containers on the fly

Tags: docker

Brand spanking new to Docker here. I have Docker running on a remote VM and am running a single dummy container on it (I can verify the container is running by issuing a `docker ps` command).

I'd like to secure my Docker installation by giving the `docker` user non-root access:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker myuser
```

But I'm afraid to muck around with Docker while any containers are running in case "hot deploys" create problems. So this has me wondering, in general: if I want to do *any* sort of operational work on Docker (daemon, I presume) while there are live containers running on it, what do I have to do? Do all containers need to be stopped/halted first? Or will Docker keep on ticking and apply the updates when appropriate?

Same goes for the containers themselves. Say I have a `myapp-1.0.4` container deployed to a Docker daemon. Now I want to deploy `myapp-1.0.5`, how does this work? Do I stop `1.0.4`, remove it from Docker, and then deploy/run `1.0.5`? Or does Docker handle this for me under the hood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I want to do any sort of operational work on Docker (daemon, I presume) while there are live containers running on it, what do I have to do? Do all containers need to be stopped/halted first? Or will Docker keep on ticking and apply the updates when appropriate?

Usually, all containers are stopped first.
That happen typically when I upgrade docker itself: I find all my container stopped (except the [data containers, which are just created](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container), and remain so)

> Say I have a myapp-1.0.4 container deployed to a Docker daemon. Now I want to deploy myapp-1.0.5, how does this work? Do I stop 1.0.4, remove it from Docker, and then deploy/run 1.0.5? Or does Docker handle this for me under the hood?

That depend on the nature and requirements of your app: for a completely stateless app, you could even run 1.0.5 (with different host ports mapped to your app exposed port), test it a bit, and stop 1.0.4 when you think 1.0.5 is ready.

But for an app with any kind of shared state or resource (mounted volumes, shared data container, ...), you would need to stop and rm 1.0.4 before starting the new container from 1.0.5 image.

---

> (1) why don't you stop them [the data containers] when upgrading Docker?

Because... they were never started in the first place.
In the lifecycle of a container, you can create, then start, then run a container. But a data container, by definition, has no process to run: it just exposes `VOLUME`(S), for other container to mount (`--volumes-from`)

> (2) What's the difference between a data/volume container, and a Docker container running, say a full bore MySQL server?

The difference is, again, that a data container doesn't run any process, so it doesn't exit when said process stops. That never happens, since there is no process to run.
The MySQL server container would be running as long as the server process doesn't stop.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks @VonC (+1) that makes sense. Two quick followups about the data containers, if you don't mind: (1) why don't you stop them when upgrading Docker? And (2) What's the difference between a data/volume container, and a Docker container running, say a full bore MySQL server? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb I have updated the answer to address your follow-up questions.

Comment: Thanks again, makes sense!